# Use different formula based on a string found in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

IF the word "DOG" is found in string

[image: 1]

IF the word "CAT" is found in string

[image: 2]

Seeking help in revising vba code to change the formula to be used if a certain text eg. "DOG" or "CAT" is found in a cell under column A

```vb
Sub Name_Extraction()

x = 2
n = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For Line = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If InStr(1, Range("B" & Line), "OLT") <> 0 Then
    Range("B2:B" & n).Formula = "=MID(LEFT(RC[-1][,FIND("(FOR",RC[-1])-1),FIND("DOG",RC[-1])+3,LEN(RC[-1]))"
    
    Else
    
    Range("B2:B" & n).Formula = "=MID(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND("(FOR",RC[-1])-1),FIND("CAT",RC[-1])+3,LEN(RC[-1]))"
    
    End If
    
Next Line        
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems all examples contain either Cat or Dog, wouldn't this work then: `=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),,2)`

Comment: Another possible variant of a formula: `=MID(A3,5,FIND(" (",A3)-5)`

Answer (score 0):

- The formula on cell B2 is

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("cat",A2),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH("dog",A2),0)>0,MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,IFERROR(SEARCH("FOR",A2),0)-FIND(" ",A2)-3),"")
```

Please try.

```vb
Sub Name_Extraction()
    Dim n As Long
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B2:B" & n).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(""cat"",RC[-1]),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH(""dog"",RC[-1]),0)>0,MID(RC[-1],FIND("" "",RC[-1])+1,IFERROR(SEARCH(""FOR"",RC[-1]),0)-FIND("" "",RC[-1])-3),"""")"
End Sub
```

- If you are using Excel 365, `let` formula is

```
=LET(c,IFERROR(SEARCH("cat",A2),0),
    d,IFERROR(SEARCH("dog",A2),0),
    s,FIND(" ",A2),
    e,IFERROR(SEARCH("FOR",A2),0),
    IF(c+d>0,MID(A2,s+1,e-s-3),""))
```

- If the first word is `cat` or `dog` anyway, the formula coulbe be simpler.

```
=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,FIND(" (",A2)-FIND(" ",A2)-1)
```

Comment: noted on this...thank you very much

Comment: If the first word is always either "cat" or "dog," the formula could be simplified. `=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,FIND(" (",A2)-FIND(" ",A2)-1)`